# Drupal Theming - Different themes for each webform

Tags: drupal

I am including a webform block in a page using module invoke.

The block is included as a node, and says "Submitted by  admin  on Wed, 2010-01-20 14:06" on top of the form. The devel template information is as follows:
**Template called:**
    node.tpl.php
**File used:**
    sites/all/themes/david01/node.tpl.php
**Candidate template files:**
    node-webform.tpl.php < node.tpl.php

I know how to theme the webform (webform-form-###.tpl.php), but how do I theme this node in particular (node-webform-####.tpl.php is not a candidate!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define `node-[nid].tpl.php` - a template for a single node.
Also look through this [post](http://drupal.org/node/79086).